# 403 Access Denied

Tags: php, curl, phpmyadmin

I have looked at the various questions related to my question but haven't found any working answers.

I currently have a server on byethost for testing my application (When I know it works, I'm moving it to GoDaddy). I am trying to edit information placed in a table of my database. When I use cURL to test this out it returns with 403 Access Denied. It could be the permissions within the database but I never set any permissions up. I can Add, View and Delete from my database I only have issues editing the information within the database.

If anyone has any insight to why this may be happening, please let me know.

John

Comment: Are you trying to modify database throught cURL? What kind of database? How are you using cURL?

Comment: Using cURL commands to edit the information. curl -i -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"colum1":"value1", "column2":"value2"}' http://ipaddress/functionname/referenceValue.

Comment: Or is editing information restricted to localhost only?

Comment: access to your server via cURL might be restricted. This is most likely a server configuration issue or an authentication issue (if it's setup on the server).

Comment: Then why would I be able to add, view and delete via cURL but not edit

Comment: Ok forget the last comment. I must have added in the previous records manually to test out. Guess I'll need to test them out locally instead of on a server. I can only use get, head, options and trace Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with the provider having certain cURL commads disabled.

Comment: So do you mean that, following kind of `cURL` commands might work?

curl -X GET http://appstests.byethost.com/api/TestApi/users/

Comment: but the question for me it is sending me `403 - Forbidden` page.